# suggestion to configure squid to allow internet connection for added mac address in configruation table

Tags: proxy, centos, squid

I have configured squid proxy server in centos. The proxy has to block all internet connection but it should offer internet connection to added only mac address in squid configuration. Below is my squid configuration,

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

#configuration added to increase perfomance
cache_mem 100 MB

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443          
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
visible_hostname abc.efg.com
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
acl director  arp 38:ea:a7:fc:ce:b6
# BLITZNET IP ACL END
http_access allow  director
# BLITZNET ACCESS END
cache_effective_user squid
cache_effective_group squid
http_access deny all
```

The above configuration has to allow internet connection only to mac 38:ea:a7:fc:ce:b6.But it allow internet connection to all computer which are connected to it.

Something wrong with my squid configuration. please help me get through.

Thanks

Found solution to my problem Currently updated my configuration with the below configuratin
and it does my job

```
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32

#configuration added by to increase perfomance

cache_mem 100 MB

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

#hostname details
visible_hostname abc.com 

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

http_access deny localhost 
# BLITZNET IP ACL END
# BLITZNET ACCESS END

http_access deny all
```

Thanks

Comment: What's 38:ea:a7:fc:ce:b6? A router? a terminal server? Can you describe your scenario a little better.

Comment: 38:ea:a7:fc:ce:b6 is a pc which has mac address connected to squid network.

Comment: i am mac using mac based filter in squid